# Connected sum of compact and orientable manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

It we have that $n$-manifolds $M$, $M'$, $N$, and $N'$ are compact and orientable, does it follow that if $M\#N$ is homeomorphic to $M'\#N'$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to $M'$ or $N'$ and $N$ is homeomorphic to $N'$ or $M'$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - take, for example, $M$ to be the connected sum of $3$ $2$-tori, $N$ a torus, and $M'=N'$ both the connected sum of $2$ tori.

Both $M \# N$ and $M' \# N'$ give the compact orientable manifold of genus $4$.

Comment: Would it still be untrue if we also restrict them to being prime?

Comment: I‘m not familiar with manifold theory but [this](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Prime_decomposition_theorem_in_high_dimensions) seems to be a counterexample. There *is* a unique prime decomposition for $3$-manifolds though.